# How to install libvirt-go? (pkg-config)

Tags: go, installation, package, libvirt

Libvirt was installed with "dnf install". For libvirt-go - $ go get github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go.
As a result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX2NU.png)

How I can change PKG_CONFIG_PATH? Or how to install libvirt-go right?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Most linux packages have a separate "-dev" package with the headers and pkgconfig data.

Comment: Linux - Fedora 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the libvirt development package, eg libvirt-devel on Fedora/RHEL/Centos, or libvirt-dev on Debian/Ubuntu.

The libvirt-go build process will just query 'pkg-config' to find out where it is installed, so if you did have it installed in a non-standard location (eg /opt/libvirt), then you would do   'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/libvirt/lib/pkgconfig' and then libvirt-go would find that.